# How do I call a SQL Server stored procedure from PHP using PDO_SQLSRV that returns a value?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014 that takes two integers as input and returns an integer. Below is the code to create the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_MergePerson_AuditLog_CheckLogForDuplicate]
    @Person1_ID INT,
    @Person2_ID INT,
    @RowCount INT OUTPUT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT
        @RowCount = COUNT(mpal.Transaction_ID)
    FROM
        MergePersonAuditLog mpal
    WHERE
        @Person1_ID = @Person2_ID
        AND @Person2_ID = @Person1_ID
RETURN @RowCount
```

Basically, it just takes two ids and sees if a comparison has been made before, just in a different order. Below is the PHP code:

```
// Connecting to DB
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=IP;Database=DB", "user", "pwd");
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error connecting to server $e");
}

// Arrays that will hold people IDs
$person1Array = array();
$person2Array = array();

// Holds the row count used to see if a comparison has already been performed
$rowcount = 5; // Setting to 5 to make sure the stored procedure is actually setting the value.

// Query to get the people that will be compared
$query = "SELECT p.PersonID 
          FROM Person p 
          WHERE (p.StudentNumber IS NULL OR p.StudentNumber = '') 
            AND (p.StaffNumber IS NULL OR p.StaffNumber = '')
          ORDER BY
            p.PersonID";
$stmt = $conn->query($query);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $person1Array[] = $value;
    }
}
$person2Array = $person1Array;

// Begin the comparisons
print "Beginning the comparisons <br>";
foreach ($person1Array as $person1id) {
    foreach ($person2Array as $person2id) {
        print "Checking $person1id and $person2id <br>";
        if ($person1id != $person2id) {
            print "Not the same. Continuing.<br>";

            // Checking to see if the comparison has already been made
            $query = "{? = call p_MergePerson_AuditLog_CheckLogForDuplicate(?, ?)}";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $rowcount, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT,4);
            $stmt->bindParam(2, $person1id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(3, $person2id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            print $rowcount . "<br>";

        }   
    }
}
print "FINISHED! <br>";

$stmt = null;
$conn = null;

?>
```

When I run this code, 5 is still being printed for $rowcount even though it should be set to 0 by the stored procedure. If the value is 0, more code will be executed that I didn't include, but I want to get this part right first. Running the procedure in management studio works fine. Can someone tell me why $rowcount is not getting updated? I am running php 5.6 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer that worked for me. I read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626303(v=sql.105).aspx which doesn't have anything to do with PDO_SQLSRV, but with sqlsrv_connect(). In that article, it stated the last parameter was the output parameter. I changed my code to look like this:

```
    // Checking to see if the comparison has already been made
    $query = "{call p_MergePerson_AuditLog_CheckLogForDuplicate(?, ?, ?)}";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $person1id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $person2id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $rowcount, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT,4);
    $stmt->execute();
    print $rowcount . "\n";
```

Basically, I moved the "?" From the beginning of the call statement to the end and moved the bindParam to the end as well. That seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the return value via a `select` statement:

```
$query = "select p_MergePerson_AuditLog_CheckLogForDuplicate(?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $person1id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $person2id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

The approved answer doesn't actually answer the question.

RETURN @RowCount isn't actually picked by php.

The reason the example works is because @RowCount is a parameter and is bound in php.

So within the TSQL it's the line @RowCount = COUNT(mpal.Transaction_ID) that passes back the value not the RETURN statement. That is, you could remove the return statement and it would still work.

The above is a comment. The answer by Zhorov can be found at   [How to get the return value from a stored procedure? PHP | PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68539618/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-stored-procedure-php-pdo)

Comment: is this an answer to the question or just commentary on another answer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35284382)

Comment: @PaulS - I was merely pointing out tha the approved answer was not actually answering the question which was about grabbing the RETURN value. Instead the approved answer indicated how to obtain a reponse message. I also pointed to the correct answer via a link to another post