# How to get the return value from a stored procedure? PHP | PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I  want to show the return value of SP of SQL Server. I tried to use this way, but I wasn't successful.

I am using the PHP PDO for the database connection and I am executing an SQL Server stored procedure.

```
$feesObj = new FeesConfig('config/fees.ini');
$feesConfig = $feesObj->getFeesConfig();
                                
$studentId = $user->getSyStudentId();
$statement = $conn->prepare('exec ?= usp_GetStudentDegreeLevel ?');
$statement->bindParam(1, $retval, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);
$statement->bindParam(2, $studentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump("return value". $retval);exit;
```

Output of this SP Execution

```
NULL
```

Expected Result

```
1
```

Where I am wrong with this code. I am calling the SQL Server SP.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641726/get-return-value-from-sql-stored-procedure-using-php

Answer (score 0):

**Original answer (with my usual approach for getting the return value(s) of possible output parameters and the return value of the stored procedure):**

You may consider the following:

- The return value from a stored procedure is an integer, so you need to use an appropriate binding.
- In case of an `OUTPUT` parameter you need to set the `maxLength` parameter in the `PDOStatement::bindParam` call. As is explained in the documentation, to *...indicate that a parameter is an OUT parameter from a stored procedure, you must explicitly set the length*.
- You need to fetch all possible result sets (using `PDOStatement::nextRowset`) to get the value of an output parameter. Or, as an option, in case of an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement, put `SET NOCOUNT ON` as first line in your stored procedure. As is explained in the documentation, this statement *... stops the message that shows the count of the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure from being returned as part of the result set*.

Below is a simplified example using SQL Server 2017, PHP 7.4.8 and PHP Driver for SQL Server 5.8:

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetStudentDegreeLevel 
    @StudentId INT  
AS  
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Information about the student' AS StudentInfo;
    RETURN 1;
END
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$server   = 'server\instance,port';
$database = 'database';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM);
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error connecting to SQL Server".$e->getMessage());
}

try { 
    // 
    $sql = "EXEC ? = usp_GetStudentDegreeLevel ?";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    if ($statement === false) {
        echo print_r($conn->errorInfo(), true);
        exit;
    }
    // Execution
    $retval    = 0;
    $studentId = 1;
    $statement->bindParam(1, $retval, PDO::PARAM_INT | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, PDO::SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT_DEFAULT_SIZE);
    $statement->bindParam(2, $studentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if ($statement->execute() === false) {
        echo print_r($conn->errorInfo(), true);
        exit;
    }   
    // Fetch data. 
    do {
       if ($statement->columnCount() > 0) {
           while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
              echo print_r($row, true); 
           };
        };  
    } while ($statement->nextRowset());
    //
    var_dump("Return value: " . $retval); 
    $statement = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;   
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

Result:

```
Array ( [StudentInfo] => Information about the student ) string(15) "Return value: 1"
```

**Update (an example, which reproduces the unexpected return value):**

The only way I can reproduce this error is the combination of:

- Using `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` as default error handling mode.
- An error in the stored procedure and/or an error in the SQL statement.
- No checks whether the result from the `PDO::prepare` and/or `PDOStatement::execute` calls is successful or not.

PHP code:

```
// PDO object with default error handling (PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT, but for PHP version before 8.0.0)
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM);

// SQL statement with error
$sql = "EXEC ? = usp_GetStudentDegreeLevel ,?";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(1, $retval,  PDO::PARAM_STR | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 1);
$statement->bindParam(2, $studentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//
var_dump($retval);
```

Result:

```
NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

@ Zhorov - thanks for your answer - it came in handy. The RETURN value seems to be in the second rowset.

If fetchAll is used it will need to be followed by nextrowset to get the value of the RETURN value.

```
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$statement->nextRowset()
var_dump($retval);
```